# Clojure writing files slowly

Tags: java, clojure, io, leiningen

We have a Clojure application that takes a dataset (~3000 rows) and writes it to a local file using spit. It works great on the machine where it was written, but on every other machine that pulls down the git code, the write step is agonizingly slow. The process takes seconds on the original machine, but takes upwards of ten minutes on every other machine.

The two primary machines in question (the developer’s machine and mine) are both Manjaro Arch Linux systems with comparable specs and configurations. We are both pulling from the same Git source, and both pulling the same data.

We have confirmed that the code stills runs on my machine, since it completes if I try to write only the first ten lines of the dataset (even that still takes almost a minute).

CPU and RAM are barely touched during the process on both machines and the output filesize is less than a MB.

We get the same problem if we use the Java.io library with clojure.data.csv or dk.ative.docjure.spreadsheet instead of spit.

The abstracted datashape is:

```
[["Name" "Price"]
 ["Foo Widget" 100]
 ["Bar Widget" 200]]
```

(but of course is greater than 3000 rows)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have or could you provide a MWE that reproduces the issue?

Comment: This is probably so obvious a question that you have already thought of it, and it does not apply to you, but is the fast machine writing to a truly local file system, but the others are writing to a file system mounted over a network?

Comment: You mention number of rows, but do you know the size in bytes of the file being written in seconds on the original machine?  Is the size of the file written on the other machines where it is agonizingly slow the same?

Comment: Adding to the two comments above me: *after* you've verified file size is the same can you use another utility to just copy the data (like `cp`) and see if there are still significant differences? This can help verify if its clojure related or something more low-level.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!

@mvarela - Sure we're working on code for an MWE now

Comment: @andy_fingerhut - Yes, unfortunately it's not that simple; in both cases the file is being written to the local system of whatever machine the application is on. The size of the file is 442KB, and it's the same file regardless of the machine where the application is installed

Comment: @Reut Sharabani - Yeah, I've taken a copy of the file written on the working machine and copied it to the problem machine in question, and there are no slow-downs; it copies in less than a second

Comment: @amberk12 Are you sure its the actual writing of the file that is slow? Can you share the csv specific code? Clojure's csv library is very limited and IIRC its easy to shot yourself in the leg with it. Can you load the entire csv to memory (using `doall`) and then dump it to a file and time the two operations (`doall` vs `spit`). Maybe the csv part is the slow part.

Comment: This looks very strange. The file size and the dataset size are both really small so it should be very fast. It would help if you could share a complete code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so while we were working on the code example to share, we received some suggestions from another source that have resolved the issue.

1. We changed the reader to use an input stream instead of reading in the whole file
2. We wrapped the writer in a `doall` as was also suggested by @Reut Sharabani

The underlying issue seems to be how each machine was handling laziness

Thanks to everyone that responded!